# Setting body class while using partials in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Another AngularJS newbie question.

I've got an index.html, controllers, and partials.

My `<body>` tag is in the index.html ... and I want to set the class for the body in my controller.

So I tried sticking a value in `$scope.body_class` and then referencing that variable in my index.html, like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myGreatApp">
...
<body ng-class="{body_class}"> {{body_class}} Hi!
```

But `body_class` doesn't return a value.

How do I get `body_class` to return a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, the controller has to be defined on the element or any parent element for it to be able to interact with the directives (or you will have to inject the $rootScope and use it instead) and, the ng-class directive accepts a hash, so

```
<body ng-controller="YourController" ng-class="{body_class: <expression>}"> {{body_class}} Hi!
```

and if `<expression>` is thruthy, it will get a html `class` that corresponds to the key in the hash.

```
<body ng-controller="YourController" ng-class="{body_class: true}" class="body_class"> whatever value $scope.body_class has Hi!
```

If you dont need to declare the class name in the markup, the ng-class directive also accepts a direct binding, so you can instead:

```
<body ng-controller="YourController" ng-class="body_class"> {{body_class}} Hi!
```

[ng-class documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

*Controller*

```
function SampleCtrl($scope){
$scope.MyClass = 'Hello'
}
```

*HTML*

```
<body data-ng-app="" data-ng-controller='SampleCtrl'>
<div data-ng-class="MyClass">Hello World
</div>
</body>
```

[Sample JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bWAD/)

Comment: If you use `$rootScope` you don't have to have controller placed on body tag.

Comment: its just for the sample only